# Powershell script to list files without folder names

Tags: powershell

I open a PS in a folder then use
`dir -name > asd.xls -recurse`.

How can I modify this so it doesn't incude folders in the filenames?

Comment: Try `(Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse).Name | Set-Content 'asd.txt'`

Comment: Just so you know Gab Bu that `Get-ChildItem` and `Dir` is the same command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `-name`, try using

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse).Name > asd.xls
```

and be aware that you won’t get a valid Excel workbook that way. You *can* get a valid CSV that can be loaded into Excel with

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse) | Select-Object -Property Name | Export-CSV -Path asd.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually it worked the first way, an excel was created.

Comment: @GabBu - It may have created a file with an Excel workbook _name_, but Excel probably would not recognize it, and consider it corrupt.